# C# Rotate bits to left overflow issue

Tags: c#, bit

I've been trying to get this to work for several days now, I've read a thousand guides and people's questions, but still, I can't find a way to do it properly.

What I want to do is to rotate the bits to the left, here's an example.

Original number = 10000001 = 129
What I need = 00000011 = 3

I have to rotate the bits to left a certain amount of times (it depends on what the user types), here's what I did:

```
byte b = (byte)129;
byte result = (byte)((byte)b << 1);
Console.WriteLine(result);

Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
Console.ReadKey(true);
```

The issue with this it that it causes an error (OverflowException) when I try to use the (<<) operator with that number (note that if I put a number which first bit is a 0; example: 3 = 00000011; it works as intended and it returns a 6 as a result.

The problem is, if the first bit is a 1, it gives me the (OverflowException) error. I know this isn't rotating, its just a shifting, the first bit goes away and on the end of the byte a 0 pops up, and I can then change it with an OR 000000001 operation to make it a 1 (if the first bit was a 1, if it was a 0 I just leave it there).

Comment: Have u tried using the unchecked keyword?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/a569z7k8.aspx

Comment: Are you only doing it with bytes? If so you could cheat a bit by shifting as an int and then using a mask to truncate it once you are done, potentially using a different mask and shift to get the bits to put on the lower end.

Comment: When I do this, I don't get an `OverflowException`.

Answer (score 8):

You're getting an overflow exception because you're operating in a checked context, apparently.

You can get around that by putting the code in an unchecked context - or just by making sure you don't perform the cast back to `byte` on a value that can be more than 255. For example:

```
int shifted = b << rotateLeftBits;
int highBits = shifted & 0xff;
int lowBits = shifted >> 8; // Previously high bits, rotated
byte result = (byte) (highBits | lowBits);
```

This will work for rotate sizes of up to 8. For greater sizes, just use `rotateLeftBits % 8` (and normalize to a non-negative number if you might sometimes want to rotate right).

Comment: I like this for working with different shift amounts. :)

Answer (score 4):

`<<` is a shift operator, not a rotate one.

If you want to rotate, you can use (with suitable casting):

```
b = (b >> 7) | ((b & 0x7f) << 1);
```

The first part of that gets the leftmost bit down to the rightmost, the second part shifts all the other left.

The `or`-ing them with `|` combines the two.

Comment: You'll need a cast in there apparently (so linqpad tells me).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers!

Shortly after i made this post i came up with an idea to solve this problem, let me show you (Before you ask, it works!):

```
byte b = (byte)129; 
b = (byte)((byte)b & 127); 
byte result = (byte)((byte)b << 1); 
result = (byte)((byte)result | 1); 
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

What this does is, removes the first bit (in case if it is a 1) it shifts to the left that zero (doesnt generate overflow) and once the shift is over, it changes that 0 back to 1. If that first bit was a 0, it will just move that zero (note that this is just a piece of the whole code, and as it is partially written in spanish (the comments and variables) i doubt you will understand most of it, so i decided to take out the problematic part to show it to you guys!

I will still try the things you told me and see how it goes, again, thanks a lot for your answers!

Comment: I don't think that's quite right. Your fourth line sets the low bit to 1 regardless of what the high bit was to start with. So bit pattern 00000001 becomes 00000011, for example.

Comment: As i said before, this is just a part of a bigger code, in the complete code, there is an operation of the number AND 128 to know if the first bit is a 1 or a 0, and depending of that result, it will enter the IF or the ELSE, in the IF ill do that thing i wrote down, on the ELSE ill just do the normal << operation.

Answer (score 0):

please try this function - rotates in both directions (left and right rotation of an 8 bit value) [I didn't tested that function!]

```
// just for 8Bit values (byte)
byte rot(byte value, int rotation)
    {
        rotation %= 8;

        int result;
        if(rotation < 0)
        {
            result = value << (8 + rotation);
        }
        else
        {
            result = value << rotation;
        }

        byte[] resultBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(result);
        result = resultBytes[0] | resultBytes[1];

        return (byte)result;
    }

short rot(short value, int rotation) { ... }
int rot(int value, int rotation) { ... }
```