# Right Circular Shift C#

Tags: c#

How can I do Right circular shift in C#?

I use this function to do Left Circular Shift.

My function works as the following:

1100 -> shift by 1 => 1001
1100 -> shift by 2 => 0011

I need to have another one to do the Right Circular Shift?
1001 -> shift 1 => 1100
and so on

```
private string leftRotateShift(string key, int shift)
        {
            string res = "";
            string[] result = new string[key.Length];
            char[] a = key.ToCharArray();
            int index = 0;
            for (int i = shift; index < a.Length; i++)
            {
                result[index++] = a[i % a.Length].ToString();
            }
            res = string.Join("", result);
            return res;
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure how right shift is different from Left... I thought it is the same thing with just `shift` vs. `length-shift` .

Comment: What you're calling a "circular shift" is normally called "rotation." This answer shows how to do a left rotation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23296021/c-sharp-rotate-bits-to-left-overflow-issue. Search Stack Overflow and you'll find lots of questions about how to do it in C and one or two for C#.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26520607/circular-left-rotation-algorithm-in-c-sharp, which is probably closer to what you want.

Comment: Your example is a bit odd. I thought it is binary, but actually that's a string, so I wonder why not use "abcd" -> "dabc" as an example. Is that by intention or do you later parse that string into a value (like int)? The performance of converting a value into a string and back into a value is probably miserable, compared to a real bit operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `0 <= shift`, try

```
private string leftRotateShift(string key, int shift)
{
    shift %= key.Length;
    return key.Substring(shift) + key.Substring(0, shift);
}

private string rightRotateShift(string key, int shift)
{
    shift %= key.Length;
    return key.Substring(key.Length - shift) + key.Substring(0, key.Length - shift);
}
```